# How to select a row of a dataframe in python randomly, but having duplicated rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i trying to learn python, but i'm stucked in a problem. I need to select X rows of a DataFrame randomly, and i'm doing it with `sample.(frac=X)`, but in my case i can have duplicated rows, and the `sample()` don't do that.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
dfSub = dataFrame.groupby(self.column, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=self.percentage)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

How can i select randomly with chances of duplicate rows??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called random sampling with replacement, i.e. after drawing a ball from the urn, you place it back in the urn so it can be drawn again.

All you need is to set the `replace` parameter to `True`:

```
lambda x: x.sample(frac=self.percentage, replace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. I had read the pandas documentation and had't seen the parameter `replace`.

Comment: Cool, great news! If this helped, would you please accept my answer with the tick on the left? This helps others find the correct solution, and increases my reputation :)